# Problem involving complex numbers and modules

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

During my complex numbers course, I came into the following problem:
Let $z_k$ be complex numbers such that $z_k= \cos \frac {5k-4}{9}\pi + i \sin \frac {5k-4}{9}\pi$, where $k \in \{ 1,2,3 \}.$ Determine $z \in \Bbb C$ such that 
$$2z^3= \frac {|z|+z_1}{1+z_1+z_1z_2}+\frac {|z|+z_2}{1+z_2+z_2z_3}+\frac {|z|+z_3}{1+z_3+z_3z_1}.$$

Comment: Show some effort: what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to plug in $z_1,z_2,z_3$ into the equation, but I didn't get anywhere. I have tried to use some trigonometric formular, but it didn't work.

Comment: @I.Stefan Have you noticed that $\;z_k^9=(-1)^k\;$, for example? And also that $\;|z_k|=1\;$ ?

Comment: Yes, I have noticed these things.

Comment: Do you mean $|z|$ or $|z_1|$ and so forth?

Comment: 3 times $|z|$ in the right hand side

Comment: @I.Stefan Good. Then you know that  $\;z_2\;$ is a primitive root of unit of order *at most* $\;9\;$ (in fact, of order $\;3\;$ ...) , whereas $\;z_1,\,z_2\;$ are primitive roots of unit of order $\;18\;$ . This already is a beginning.

Comment: Yes, but this is the very beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Brute force
\begin{align*}
  z_1 z_2 z_3 &= \operatorname{cis} \frac{(1+6+11)\pi}{9} \\
 &= 1 \\
  \frac{|z|+z_{1}}{1+z_1+z_1 z_2} \color{red}{\times \frac{z_3}{z_3}} &=
  \frac{z_3(|z|+z_1)}{z_3+z_3 z_1+1} \\
  \frac{|z|+z_1}{1+z_1+z_1 z_2}+
  \frac{|z|+z_3}{1+z_3+z_3 z_1} &=
  \frac{(1+z_3)|z|+z_3(1+z_1)}{1+z_3+z_3 z_1}
  \color{red}{\times \frac{z_2}{z_2}} \\
  &= \frac{z_2(1+z_3)|z|+z_2 z_3+1}
          {z_2+z_2 z_3+1} \\
  2z^3 &=
  \frac{|z|+z_2}{1+z_2+z_2 z_3}+
  \frac{z_2(1+z_3)|z|+z_2 z_3+1}
          {z_2+z_2 z_3+1} \\
  &= |z|+1 \\
  2|z|^3 &= |z|+1 \\
  (|z|-1)(2|z|^2+2|z|+1) &= 0 \\
  |z| &= 1 \\
  z^{3} &= 1 \\
  z &= \operatorname{cis} \frac{2\pi k}{3}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you! By brute force you mean that you plugged in the values of all trigonometric functions?

Comment: Yes, with the help of **Mathematica** or **WolframAlpha**.